# How do I force clustering of data in a specific evident pattern?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a large set of 'Vehicle speed vs Engine RPM' values for a vehicle. I'm try to predict the time spent by the vehicle on each gear.

I ran K-Means clustering on the dataset and got the following result:
[image: Vehicle Speed vs Engine RPM (~86000 points)]

Clearly, my algorithm has failed to capture the evident pattern. I want to force K-Means (or any other clustering algorithm, for that matter) to cluster data along the six sloped lines. Snippet of relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# Importing the dataset
data = pd.read_csv('speedRpm.csv')
print(data.shape)
data.head()

# Getting the data points
f1 = data['rpm'].values
f2 = data['speed'].values
X = np.array(list(zip(f1, f2)))

# Number of clusters
k = 5

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
# Fitting the input data
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)
# Getting the cluster labels
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
# Centroid values
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

labeled_array = {i: X[np.where(kmeans.labels_ == i)] for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters)}

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(k):
        points = np.array([X[j] for j in range(len(X)) if kmeans.labels_[j] == i])
        ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s=7, c=colors[i])
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='*', s=200, c='#050505')

plt.show()
```

How do I make sure the clustering algorithm captures the right pattern, even though it possibly isn't the most efficient?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Ran the same set of points using DBSCAN this time. After playing around with the `eps` and `min_samples` values for sometime, got the following result:

[image]

Although, still not perfect and way too many outliers, the algorithm is beginning to capture the linear trend.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# Importing the dataset
data = pd.read_csv('speedRpm.csv')
print(data.shape)
data.head()

# Getting the values and plotting it
f1 = data['rpm'].values
f2 = data['speed'].values
X = np.array(list(zip(f1, f2)))

# DBSCAN

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=1.1, min_samples=3).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print "Estimated Number of Clusters", n_clusters_

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Comment: At least scale your data such that the stretched blobs look more like circles. With the right seeds KMeans or another clustering algorithm, like mixture of gaussians should perform better.

Comment: Another approach would be to use RANSAC or another robust regression algorithm to fit one blob with a line, then remove data around this line and iterate.

Comment: How did you end up with what is clearly a mix of 6 linear trends, while the vehicle under examination likely has a 5-speed transmission, judging by by your code example (it sets `k=5`)?

Comment: @LeoK k=5 means that the clustering algorithm will generate 5 centres, which it appears to from his image (exes and colors). the "6 linear trends" you mention come from the underlying data. There doesn't seem to be a discongruency there to me

Comment: what I was asking for is whether the data is from a 6-speed car - as it seems to be (while you're trying to group it into 5 groups, which can't give correct grouping, even if there weren't other problems)

Comment: @LeoK, Its a 5 + 1 reverse gear. I'm thinking the lowest linear trend is the time spent on reverse gear.

Comment: @rocksportrocker, thanks for the reply. I will try RANSAC. I ran the same with DBSCAN as suggested by the answers below. Got a better result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### High Level

There are two major options here:

1. Transform your data so that k-means-style clustering algorithms succeed
2. Pick a different algorithm

Minor option:

1. Tweak kmeans by forcing the initialization to be smarter

---

### Option 2

Python has a good description of several clustering algorithms [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) . From the link, a (crudely cropped) helpful graphic:

[image]

This row looks similar to your dataset; have you tried a Gaussian mixture model? A [GMM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) has few well known theoretical properties, but it works by assigning probabilities that points belong to each cluster center based on a posterior calculated from the data. You can often initialize it with kmeans, which Sklearn does for you.

Similarly, desnity-based clustering algorithms ([DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN), e.g.), seem like a logical choice. Your data has a nice segmentation of dense clusters, and this seems like a good topological property to be filtering for. In the image on the linked wikipedia page:

[image]

they offer the caption:

> DBSCAN can find non-linearly separable clusters. This dataset cannot
>   be adequately clustered with k-means

which seems to speak to your troubles.

---

### More on your troubles

Kmeans is an extremely versatile algorithm, but it is not globally optimal and suffers from a lot of weak-points. [Here is dense reading](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/clustering.pdf)

In addition to problems like the [mickey mouse problem](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0162259), kmeans is often trying to minimize simple euclidean distance to the centroids. While this makes a lot of sense for a lot of problems, it doesn't make sense in yours, where the skew of the clusters means that isn't quite the correct measure. Notice that other algorithms like agglomerative/hierarchical clustering, shown above, that use similar measures, have similar trappings.

I haven't covered transforming your data or tweaking kmeans because the latter requires actually hacking into (or writing your own) clustering algorithm (I don't recommend for a simple exploratory problem given the coverage of sklearn and similar packages), where the former seems like a local solution sensitive to your exact data. [ICA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_vs_pca.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-ica-vs-pca-py) might be a decent start, but there's a lot of options for that task

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @en_Knight! Ran it with DBSCAN and got better results

Answer (score 2):

k-means (and other clustering algorithms quoted in the @en-knight answer) are meant for multi-dimensional data that tends to have groups of data points that are 'close' to each other (in terms of Euclidean distance), but separated spatially.

In your case, if data is considered in your un-processed input space (rpm vs velocity) the 'clusters' that are formed are very elongated and largely overlap in the region near (0,0), so most if not all methods based on Euclidean distance are bound to fail.

Your data isn't really 6 groups of 2-dimensional points that are spatially separated. Instead, it is actually a mix of 6 possible linear trends.

Therefore, the grouping should be based on x/y (the gear ratio). It is 1-dimensional: each (rpm,velocity) pair corresponds to a single (rpm/velocity) value and you want to group those.

I don't know if the k-means (or other algorithms) can take a 1-D data set, but if it cannot, you can create a new array with pairs like [0, rpm/vel] and run that through it.

You may want to look for a 1-D algorithm that's more efficient than the multi-dimensional generic ones.

This will make the graph labeling a bit more involved because the grouping is computed on a derivative data set that has a different shape (1 x samples) than the original data which is (2 x samples), but mapping them isn't difficult.

Comment: k-means and any other clustering algorithm I'm familiar with can work in 1-D. Euclidean distance is perfectly well defined along a number line

Comment: a few other nit picks :) Not all teh algorithms I "quote" group by eucliden distance. Spectral clustering, for example, is doing something else (it's more like a kernalized k-means, but that still isn't l-2 distance).  "Almost all the methods based on Euclidean distance are bound to fail" - does this include density clustering? Why so?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ALL of the algorithms - but many of them use L-2 distance or an imitation thereof and are meant for data in which the 'dimensions' mean the same thing (e.g, coordinates in physical space), here you have rpm and velocity which aren't 'comparable' to each other. Using the knowledge that (x/y) is the thing that's expected to fall into clusters seems to make sense. Density clustering *might* work, though with the noisy data shown, it will still make mistakes - your sample is less noisy than the OP's and it made visible mistakes even on it. I'd convert to 1-D in all cases.

Comment: @en_Knight: in any case, I wasn't making claims that your suggested alternatives are 'bad', any one of them could work on the 2-D input set. Nor that I know how all of them work. All I'm saying is that it is clearly a 'difficult' one when looked at as an (x,y) set, but will become easy and neatly split without errors if you use the simple transformation that I suggested.

Comment: makes sense to me, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LeoK. Will convert to a 1-D dataset and rerun!

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply your y-values by a factor of 10 or more, so they spread out along that axis.  Make sure you keep track of whether you're working with the real values or the multiplied values.